# Printing statement for wrong condition

Tags: python

I am creating a text-based adventure game in Python, but I'm having problems with my if-statements and printing the correct outcome. If the user types "yes," then both outcomes are printed and the same thing happens if the user types "no." All help is appreciated.

```
def main():
    playerLvl = 0

    treatOne = input("You find a Hershey's Bar on the floor while you are trick-or-treating. Would you like to collect the Hershey's Bar? Type yes or no.")
    print("You chose: ", treatOne, "!")

    if treatOne == "yes" or "Yes":
         playerLvl += 1
         print("Good choice! You gained points for picking up candy. Now your score is: ", playerLvl)

    if treatOne == "no" or "No":
        playerLvl -= 1
        print("Uh oh. You lost points. You're supposed to pick up candy for points. Now your score is:", playerLvl)

    else:
        print("Error. Try again.")
main()
```

Comment: Your problem is that you mean `if (treatOne == "yes") or (treatOne == "Yes"):` but wrote actually `if treatOne == ("yes" or "Yes"):` which is True for all non empty `treatOne`s - but you should do `if treatOne.lower() == "yes":` anyway...

Comment: @Spghtt Correction, they actually wrote `if (treatOne == "yes") or "Yes":`, which is *always* true, regardless of the value of `treatOne`.